# Specific phone number to use during outages, which word?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I'm looking for an adjective to indicate a phone number is specifically for use when there is an outage, for example when there is no electrical power or no running water.

I've considered 'Fault telephone number' and 'Outage telephone number', but I'm not sure what is the right word to use.

For context, this telephone number isn't for working hour questions, but specifically to notify with urgency something is not working.

Comment: Emergency number?

Comment: [*Fault reporting number?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fault+reporting+number%22)

Comment: After-hours emergency number.

Comment: All acceptable as answers, why not post them as such so I can upvote them and choose one?